# ee.Geometry.Bbox on Google Earth Engine produces a very long rectangle even though my coordinates are fine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth, google-earth-engine-python-api

According to the documentation of BBOX I must put the longitude of north east west and lat of South. When I do that I get a huge box when in reality I just need a box of size 5km for instance, not the whole map. When I try then to for example change the North to lat instead of long I get this long thin rectangle, I am not sure why this happens?

d = shapefile['geometry'][i][image: a]
[y_coord, x_coord] = np.array(d)
d = geopy.distance.geodesic(kilometers = 1)
west = d.destination(point=start, bearing=90)
north = d.destination(point=start, bearing=0)
south = d.destination(point=start, bearing=180)
[image: enter imasge description here]
east = d.destination(point=start, bearing=270)

I got the coordinates of the point I am interested in using this. It gives an array which I assume is long lat essentially, I then input these values in Bbox like this:
aoi=ee.Geometry.BBox(west[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCkKK.png),south[0],east[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCkKK.png),north[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCkKK.png))

To then export an image which in theory should be 5km for instance.

Also I am using Python but used this just to visualize the issue with my coordinates

Comment: West should be minor than east, -61.03 is greater than -61.101

Comment: This made me confused too. I get what I expect when switching west and east arguments. Why is that? https://code.earthengine.google.com/338283d934c6094400e8c822f9e80192

Comment: @ElioDiaz Thank you, yes that does sort of fix the problem, however when I do d.destination these are the values I get.
Actually the problem seems to be that I have put bearing for east at 270 when its meant to be 90?

Comment: @DanielWiell I think east bearing is meant to be 90? am I wrong to put it as 270?

Comment: @ElioDiaz I did what must be done, but now the issue is that its vertically too long. If I change the North value to a latitidue it fixes the length issue but its in the wrong location then?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, I changed the bearing of east and west with each other and also seems as though documentation of bbox maybe be incorrect since it asked for northern most long when in reality I think it should be lat since this seems to have solved my issue.